# Change UINavigation ToolBar into UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitoolbar

Is there a way to replace the toolbar in a uinavigationcontroller with a custom uiscrollview? I essentially want a toolbar that one can pan left and right and can detect tap gestures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a scroll view to a `UINavigationBar` using [`-initWithCustomView:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithCustomView%3a) on `UIBarButtonItem`.

You can also subclass `UINavigationBar`, add your scroll view as a subview, and then instantiate your navigation controller with [`-initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/initWithNavigationBarClass%3atoolbarClass%3a). Pass in `[YourCustomNavBarClass class]` to the first parameter, and the navigation controller will use your subclass whenever it needs to show a nav bar.